# Block websites programmatically

Tags: c#, web, block

The program has a black list, it contains a list of sites. When the user opens the site in IE (Firefox, Opera, Chrome) he should get an error. (For example 404).
How can I do? It is advisable not writing to the file HOSTS.
Language C#.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you can't use HOSTS?

Comment: What operating systems are you targeting and what is the environment for this? e.g. company computers or home computers?

Comment: "Can you elaborate on why you can't use HOSTS?"
-Because it is easy to change.
Targeted for MS Windows and home computers.

Comment: It's just as easy to ctrl+alt+del and kill your program though..

Comment: Don't be clever-clever, old thing!

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a Proxy server:

http://www.squid-cache.org/

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind what you're trying to do is monitoring port 80 outgoing traffic and block any requests addressed to sites/ips contained in the black list.

It's kind of complex posting for you the whole code here.

Regardless, this kind of operation is best suited to a network firewall filter than to a custom C# app that runs on the client.